# Fixing variable declaration in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react JS but know a bit of ECS. I have this code in `index.js`. But this is not rendering. What's wrong? TIA

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// Copy code here:
var elementt = <h1>Hello world</h1>

// Render the 'elementt' element
ReactDOM.render(elementt, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);

// Update the 'elementt' element using this function
function func(){
  elementt = <p>Hello Guys</p>
}

// Call the function after 3 seconds from render to update text
setInterval(func(), 3000)
```

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to call the function at the end. Make edits accordingly. I expected the function to update the element in the page since 'react.js'

Edit2: Updated the answer even more. Actually, I wanted to call the `func()` function after an interval of 3 seconds to see the content change. If it isn't possible, tell me another way. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: have you a div with id app in your index.html because works for me . [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-villani-4fdm9?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: "Guys please, this is demotivating" it also for us, if we need to writes an answer for a user with the `random_person` as name :-)

Comment: @random_person Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65823946/9071943) below for more details.

Comment: Don't worry :-)

Comment: @random_person You should read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It's not surprising that your profiles keep getting blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues you need to resolve:

1. You are missing the `return`  keyword

   ```
    function func(){
      return <p>Hello Guys</p>;
    }
   ```
2. You shouldn't use `func` as a function name. Because it'll be ambiguous with `func` keyword. Use another instead. Let's say `Welcome`

```js
function Welcome(){
  return <p>Hello Guys</p>;
}

const element = <Welcome />;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

**What happened if the function name is `func`**

```js
function func(){
  return <p>Hello Guys</p>;
}

const element = <func />;
// It's not affect
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('app'));
// the output is so weird
console.log(element);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

**Updated based on another requirement**

> Sorry, I don't 'want to return the element, but change the value of
> the element.

The `func();` should be called before `ReactDOM.render(elementt, document.getElementById('app') );` to change the value from `Hello world` to `Hello Guys`

```
var elementt = <h1>Hello world</h1>
func(); // Should call the function before to get `Hello Guys`

ReactDOM.render(elementt, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```js
// Copy code here:
var elementt = <h1>Hello world</h1>
func(); // Should call the function before to get `Hello Guys`

ReactDOM.render(elementt, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);

function func(){
  elementt = <p>Hello Guys</p>
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't 'want to return the element, but change the value of element. I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: you can do this, with this structure of the application, there is any trigger event to change the state of the component inside the function, maybe you need to look inside the setState in ReactJs but this is out of  the question scope

Comment: I totally agree with you. The OP is having some issues that I pointed out. @vincenzopalazzo

Comment: @random_person Updated my answer, pls take a look at it. **Updated based on another requirement**

Comment: @Phong is there a way to call the function after the render after a time interval. Updated the anwer as well

Comment: Easy to answer your problem here. But you should create a new question to keep the clear one as well :) @random_person

Comment: @random_person Don't forget to give me an upvote as well as mark it as resolved by clicking the tick to help the reader in the future ^^!

Comment: You can create a new question. I'm sure to help you :) @random_person

Answer (score 1):

If you are new with react Js maybe you need to start from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) where there are some instructions to use the tag with react JS.

In addition, you can use a template to understand how it works, from the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) `create-react-app` with the following command

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

But there are a lot or more tools to create a ReactJS app, such as Next.js.

In my opinion, you do not see nothings inside your app, you are missing a tag with `id=app`, and also your function is wrong because in JS you need to call return

Answer (score 0):

Remove your function and it should work. Your function modifies a constant, which will throw an error if you call. Just get rid of that `func` and your code will render Hello World.